# Why wont the Computer monitor turn on after Windows Sleeps?

Tags: windows-7, windows, sleep, hibernate

Whenever I sleep my computer (Sony VAIO F11JFX/B), when I turn it back on sometimes the screen won't turn on with it. I can use the computer but no screen.

I tried pressing the Display On/Off button, to no avail. The only way I can get out of it is by pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> which hibernates my computer, and then just turn it back on and 99% of the time this works fine. Or I can press start on my keyboard and use the arrow keys to navigate to "Sleep" and put it to sleep again to wake it up which always works.

Does anyone know why this could be happening? As a side note, I said 99% for hibernate because sometimes Windows freezes when I put it on hibernate while its trying to wake up...

Comment: Are the video drivers, BIOS and Windows Updates up to date?

Comment: Yes, excpet my graphics card drivers which I just updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your Windows system completely up-to-date?
Because as far as I can recollect, this was a bug in Windows 7 that was later fixed with a hotfix. Let me see if I can find that particular hotfix for you.

Check [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/monitor-wont-wake-up-when-coming-back-from-sleep/40c01c55-f5be-4524-9d23-130142158c30) link on Microsoft Answers. It is a long thread that addresses your exact problem.

Comment: I just checked and yes everything is (except my NVIDIA drivers which are now...) and I looked at that thread you posted...what is PLL Overvoltage?

Comment: Think of the CPU PLL voltage as a voltage that is provided to the CPU, but then “clipped” down to an approximate voltage. No matter what that input is whether 1.3v or 1.9v it is clipped (hypothetically let’s say 800mv after clipping ) that way other devices can use the PLL voltage and clip to what they need. The CPU PLL Overvoltage allows for less clipping of that voltage. It can also reduce the lifespan of the CPU, but nothing noticeable.

Comment: What do you mean by "clipping"? Decreasing the voltage?

Comment: Yes.. It decreases the voltage in a way. Though from what I understand, it actually uses a voltage clipper circuit, and not just a  step-down.